# Loading class instance into separate process using Qt

Tags: python, c++, qt, multiprocessing, qprocess

In Python on can easily do

from multiprocessing import Process
import os

```
def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

to run even a simple function inside a separate process. We can go further an create instances of classes that are loaded inside a separate process:

```
class FooClass:
    def __init__(self, ...some args...):
        ...

foo = Process(
    target=FooClass,
    args=(...some args for the constructor of Foo...)
)
bar.start()
```

How would I do that in Qt using `QProcess` if possible at all? I am interested in this approach since I want to use it in C++ as well as PySide/PyQt. I know I can just create another project where the generated binary (containing only that class and its instance) is ran as the command passed onto the `QProcess` instance but this is not what I am looking for. Not to mention that, correct me if I'm wrong, in the Python case the spawned process gets a "copy" of the working set of the parent. If I am to just create another application and run it, this is clearly not the case.

Comment: In my experience `fork()` (without `exec()`) and Qt's GUI infrastructure do not get along together -- i.e. once you've created a `QApplication` object, forking the process is not going to lead to useful behavior; presumably because Qt has to make connections with the OS's underlying window-management system, and the windowing system is not set up to deal with forking clients.  So I think if you want Qt objects in a separate Qt process you'll have to `spawn()` the new process "from scratch" and have the child process create the appropriate Qt objects itself.

Comment: Note that the spawned child process can run the same executable as the parent process, perhaps with some special arguments to let the child process know that it is a child process and/or what the parent process wants it to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard solution from Qt for running a function in a different **process**. However there is [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) and [QtConcurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html), which use threads.

The main reason for python to have a multi**process**ing module (and not just multi**thread**ing) is the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock). However when using Qt and C++ you do not have a GIL and therefore it is usally better to use multiple threads instead of multiple processes. But there are certain special cases where you would want parts of your code to run in a different process, i.e. for dropping permissions.

If you happen to run under Linux you might investigate the [fork() system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

Comment: I am well aware of the existence of `QThread`, `QRunnable` etc. I'm interested in a `QProcess` solution since it applies to both the C++ and the Python bindings of Qt. That is why I added the C++ tag. I will update the question to make this more obvious.